# ElasticBeanStalk URL directing to incorrect IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk

I have two Elastic Beanstalk environments, running java applications on tomcat. Application/Environment A uses an ALB and Application/Environment uses an network LB. Environment B is within a private subnet.

These environments have been functioning for many months, recently all Beanstalk environments on the account where rebuilt.  Whilst other EB environments have been running correctly after the rebuild.
Application A is now failing to send traffic to Application B. The EB URL of application B is set in the environment variables of Application A but URL is now pointing to a IP address to do not recognise when pinged.

If I SSH into APP A , I am able to use CURL to send JSON requests to the application running on B and get valid responses. The two severs can "see" each other and there no firewalls blocking traffic.

How can I get APP Bs elastic beanstalk URL to point at the correct IP. From what I have read this process should be automatic. I have rebuild the environment several times. The correct IP should be the underlying EC2 private IP.